# How to make a switch to true and false?

Tags: c++

I want to learn how to make compact switches, tell me if I'm doing it right or can I simplify it?

```cpp
    auto _time = 5s;
    bool save_time;
    auto fs_time = steady_clock::now();

    for(;;) {
    auto now_time = steady_clock::now();

    if (duration_cast<seconds>(now_time - fs_time) >= _time) {
       save_time = true;
    }
    else {
       save_time = false;
    }

    // CODE ....

     if(save_time) {
     // CODE ....

     }
     if(save_time) {
     // CODE 2 ....

     }
    }
```

I do this to not write the same thing repeatedly.

```cpp
    if (duration_cast<seconds>(now_time - fs_time) >= _time) {}
```

Perhaps this slows down the code when it checks it constantly.

Comment: The question is completely unclear. What to you mean by compact switches? Or what do you mean by "switch" in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compact means in one line?

```
save_time = (duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(now_time - fs_time) >= _time) ? true  : false;
```

Or even more compact as Default suggested:

```
save_time = (duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(now_time - fs_time) >= _time);
```

Regarding the use of using, have a look to this question: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: you don't need the `? true : false` part

Comment: @Default Indeed!

Comment: A Condition is Boolean by @Default